# Accessing wordpress tool in local MAMP Site

Tags: wp-admin, admin, localhost

I created a  Wordpress website locally using MAMP.  For weeks I was able to get to my website and continue creating it by clicking "start servers" and it would open the MAMP page and I would choose "my website" at the top of the page and it would take me to my website and the Wordpress tools would be there  for me to continue working.  Now when I follow those steps it takes me to the website but none of the  tools are there to continue working.  How do I access them again?  I'm completely new to all of this.

Comment: What WordPress tools do you mean? Maybe you mean you used to be logged in as soon as you went there, but now you're logged out and not sure how to edit things?

Comment: https://youlocalsiteaddress/wp-admin

Comment: You will still need to log in to WordPress. If you didn't set a username and password when creating the site, MAMP might set defaults. You will need to check their support resources for assistance in that case.